# GROUP BY with multiple nested queries T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, azure-synapse-analytics

I am trying to perform multiple counts based on different conditions and group the results by year and month.

I have a complaints table, and I want to count:

- Total Received complaints per year and month
- Received complaints per year and month which got Cancelled
- Received complaints per year and month which got Resolved, etc...

I am using multiple nested select statements to do a count for each scenario and they work on their own.
However, when I run the whole query I get an error:
Column 'db.CustomerComplaints.id_Contact' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please see my code below:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(ReceivedDate) AS 'Year',
FORMAT(ReceivedDate, 'MMMM') AS 'Month name',
COUNT(*) AS 'Received Complaints'
,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM db.CustomerComplaints t
        WHERE t.status = 'Resolved'
        AND t.id_Contact = cc.id_Contact
    ) AS 'Resolved Complaints'
,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM db.CustomerComplaints t
        WHERE t.status = 'New'
        AND t.id_Contact = cc.id_Contact
    ) AS 'New Complaints'
FROM db.CustomerComplaints cc
LEFT JOIN db.ReferralUpdates r
ON cc.id_Contact = r.Reference
WHERE r.ReferenceCode = 'Project1'
GROUP BY YEAR(ReceivedDate), FORMAT(ReceivedDate, 'MMMM')
```

What I want to get as a results is:

| Year | Month | Received Complaints | Resolved Complaints | New Complaints |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | March | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2023 | April | 15 | 10 | 5 |
| 2024 | March | 7 | 4 | 3 |

I hope my question make sense.

Comment: Why do you outer join the ReferralUpdates table? Don't you join in order to only get Project1 complaints? So use an `[INNER] JOIN` instead. (Or even better an `EXTSTS` or `IN` clause, because you only want to ensure that a Project1 reference *exists*.) Your left outer join is converted into an inner join anyway, by the way, because of `WHERE r.ReferenceCode = 'Project1'`. Outer joined rows have a ReferenceCode NULL, so the rows that you produced with your outer join get dismissed right away.

Comment: Always use the appropriate join type. When you want an outer join, have the crieteria in the `ON` clause, not in `WHERE`.

Comment: `AS 'Year'` is invalid SQL. Single quotes are for string literals, not for names. In standard SQL the name delimiter is the double quote (`"`), in SQL Server (T-SQL) it is the brackets (`[]`). It is best to avoid them altogether and just use names that work without quotes, e.g. `year` and `month_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggreation (`CASE` expressions inside the aggregation functions (`COUNT`).

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(receiveddate) AS year,
  FORMAT(receiveddate, 'MMMM') AS month_name,
  COUNT(*) AS received_complaints,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Resolved' THEN 1 END) AS resolved_complaints,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'New' THEN 1 END) AS new_complaints
FROM hug2.customercomplaints
WHERE id_Contact IN 
(
  SELECT reference
  FROM hug2.referralupdates
  WHERE referencecode = 'Project1'
)
GROUP BY YEAR(receiveddate), MONTH(receiveddate), FORMAT(receiveddate, 'MMMM')
ORDER BY YEAR(receiveddate), MONTH(receiveddate);
```

Comment: I find conditional aggregation much more readable in standard SQL, by the way, but T-SQL is not standard compliant in this regard. In standard SQL it looks like this: `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'New') AS new_complaints`.

Comment: `GROUP BY EOMONTH(receiveddate)` or `GROUP BY DATETRUNC(month, receiveddate)` is a bit simpler. Also `DATENAME(month,` is a thing